# Collection view Cell crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I was connecting my Collection view cell to a custom one but it crashes, I already wrote the classname of the custom cell and created the class, but when I am casting the dequeueReusableCell it crashes

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PlatformCollectionViewCell
    if let platformCell = cell as? PlatformCollectionViewCell {
        platformCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        platformCell.titleLabel.text = "Hola"
        return cell
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return cell
}
```

The only possible error that I found is when it gives me the error it says something like

Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x1b12070b0) to 'Quote.PlatformCollectionViewCell' (0x1000bba00).
2017-04-02 13:24:32.711435+0200 Quote[1219:351279] Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x1b12070b0) to 'Quote.PlatformCollectionViewCell' (0x1000bba00).

I don't know if is okay that it says "NameOfTheProject.Class" in the last line. I think it should say just the class but I don't know how to fix this, in the case this is the error

the class PlatformCollectionViewCell is this

//

```
import UIKit

class PlatformCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

}
```

[image: How I connected the PlatformCell]

Comment: What is PlatformCollectionViewCell? Can you show that class.? It should be sub class of UICollectionViewCell

Comment: can you share how you register your cell? `reuseIdentifier`

Comment: I already updated the question

Comment: Have you given identifier in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. The call to `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell()` is returning a normal `UICollectionViewCell`, not an instance of your custom cell.

You need to open our view controller in IB, select the cell prototype with your identifier, and use the "identity inspector" to check the class of that cell. My guess is that you forgot to switch the class to your custom cell class, `PlatformCollectionViewCell`. If so, simply change ``` UICollectionViewCell``UICollectionViewCell to ```PlatformCollectionViewCell` in the identity inspector.

Alternately, you can call `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` to register an XIB or a class name for your reuse identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Duncan's answer on `register` led me to the fix to this issue.

Before I created a custom cell, `register` looks like this:

```
self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

It missed updating this after I created a custom cell. The fix was:

```
self.collectionView!.register(MyViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. Can you elaborate your answer a bit for for understanding?

Answer (score 0):

One issue which i faced recently, with which people get confuse often. If custom class with xib, need to register xib not the class else outlets accessed in cellForItem will be nil and crash.

```
 self.collectionViewWeekCalendar.register(UINib(nibName: "CalenderCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CalenderCell")
```